# Animate changes in row layout of in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I have a RecyclerView, which nominally appears as such:

[image: Nominal List View]

When the user enters `EDIT` mode, I change the layout of the rows so that it appears as such:

[image: Editing List View]

This all works fine. My basic technique, is that the "bordered cell" layout has its start constrained to the end of the trashcan icon. I simply toggle the visibility of the trashcan icon between GONE and VISIBLE to get the layout change.

Can I animate this change? Instead of just instantly changing, I would like it to animate the change. I have tried multiple things, and nothing I try (e.g. `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition`) seems to work. I have added the following to my top level row layout:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:animationCache="true"
```

I make the change to the visibility in the ViewHolder's bind:

```
view.isRemovableIcon.isGone = isEditing.not()
```

Can I animate this layout change easily? I'd like to add the animation because it reinforces the mode toggle. But I'm not interested in having to write hundreds of lines of code for that or import frameworks/libraries. If this can be done easily, what is the magic sauce/understing I'm missing. If it won't work, what about this setup makes it not work? Is it that I'm doing it in the ViewHolder/RecyclerView thing?

## Addendum

For completeness sake, here is my custom row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rowLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:animationCache="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:persistentDrawingCache="animation">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/isRemovableIcon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_trash_fill50_mask"
        android:tint="@color/closeRed"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rowCellLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_row_border"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/isRemovableIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/centerGuide"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/accentBlue"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/centerGuide"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/probingProgressBar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestampLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/timeLabel"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nameLabel"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/centerGuide" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/probingProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/accentBlue"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/foundStateIcon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_24px"
            android:tint="@color/accentBlue"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/notFoundStateIcon"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_no_wifi_mask"
            android:tint="@color/closeRed"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you use a custom row layout?

Comment: Yes, I updated to include the layout.

Comment: Why you don't use a linear layout with horizontal orientation as top level of your custom layout? Do you have some needs with constraint layout?

Comment: _TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition_ will work. How are you using it?

Comment: @Cheticamp I had placed it in my ViewHolder update/bind method. Right before I updated the visibility on the row layout. `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(this.view as ConstraintLayout, Slide())` was the last dart I had thrown (unsuccessfully) at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in your custom row. When you want to animate the trashcan in or out ensure that the bind logic will set the icon to visible or gone as needed on the next bind.

To force the animations, notify the adapter as follows:

```
myAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, items.size, true)
```

where

*items* is your list of data.

*true* is the payload parameter that will trigger the animation. This argument just must not be null and you can tailor it to your needs.

See [notifyitemchanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyitemchanged).

The animation can be controlled with [ViewGroup#getLayoutTransition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#getLayoutTransition()) although there are default values that may be acceptable. For instance, to change the animation duration to one second, place the following in your adapter:

```
[your itemView].layoutTransition?.apply { setDuration(1000) }
```

---

I posted a [small app](https://github.com/Cheticamp/RecyclerSlideAnimation) on GitHub to demonstrate this technique.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I would never have figured that out. In particular, that it's important that you use one of adaptors "payload" variant methods to trigger changes to be animated. That's really not clear or spelled out in the documentation.